# Unlocking user Account

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying to set properties to unlock User accounts in AD and I am using the following code; the problem is that `de` does not contain `userAccountControl` and the code fails.

I can get the value of `userAccountControl` by using `DirectorySearcher` but that does not help me in setting the property using `de`. Could anyone please help me? Thanks in advance

```
String m_Path = "LDAP://" + distinguishedName;

using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(m_Path))
{
   if (de.Contains("userAccountControl")
   {
      int m_Val  = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].Value;
      de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = m_Val | 0x0001
      de.CommitChanges;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would think you need to check whether `de.Properties` contains a value of `userAccountControl`!

```
string ldapPath = "LDAP://" + distinguishedName;

using(DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
{
   // check to see if we have "userAccountControl" in the **properties** of de
   if(de.Properties.Contains("userAccountControl")
   {
      int m_Val  = (int)de.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].Value ;
      de.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = m_Val | 0x0001;

      de.CommitChanges();
   }
}
```

Also, if you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find and manipulate users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "SomeUserName");

if(user != null)
{
   // unlock user
   user.UnlockAccount();
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!